# requirejs sometimes does not load the dependent modules and gives error "jQuery" undefined

Tags: jquery, requirejs, iscroll

I am using requirejs in my current project, but sometimes its doesn't load dependency modules and throw error "jQuery" undefined... its not happen always... if i refresh the page then it works fine. I tried increasing waitSeconds but no success.

Here:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'lib/jquery-1.10.2.min',      
        'async': 'lib/async',
        'slider': 'lib/jquery.bxslider.min',
        'fixed-scroll': 'lib/iscroll',
        'validation': 'validation-framework',
        'main-nav': 'main-nav',
        'global': 'global',     
        'page-animate': 'page-details-animation',
        'details': 'page-details',
        'pageMap': 'map'
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'details': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'page-animate': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'pageAnimate.init'
        },
        'slider': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'bxSlider'
        },
        'fixed-scroll': {
            exports: 'iScroll'
        },
        'validation': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }       
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'fixed-scroll', 'page-animate', 'main-nav', 'global', 'details', 'slider', 'pageMap', 'validation'], function () {   
    $('.page-details').pageDetails();   
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the error you report and what I see in the question, I'd suggest that `'details'` needs a shim:

```
shim: {
     [...]
    'details': [ 'jquery' ]
}
```

I'm inferring this due to `$('.page-details').pageDetails()`, `pageDetails` must be provided by a jQuery plugin and that plugin looks like it would be (based on the names used) the modules declared to RequireJS as `'details'`. The error you get is consistent with this plugin not being properly shimmed. A jQuery plugin needs jQuery loaded to install itself, hence the need for the dependency.

Other things that are good to know but do not participate in the error:

- jQuery 1.10.x does not need to be shimmed. It's been true since at least 1.8. Require it as `'jquery'` (all lowercase), and you'll be fine.
- You should use the value of the `'jquery'` module instead of relying on the global `$`. So, don't do:

  ```
   require(['jquery', ...], function () {
       $.whatever();
   });
  ```

  but have function parameter named `$` that corresponds to the `'jquery'` module:

  ```
  require(['jquery', ...], function ($) {
      $.whatever();
  });
  ```

If you ever use `noConflict` or need to support multiple versions of jQuery (which may happen if you use a 3rd party library that needs a specific version), it will make your life easier.